# Unable to override and use FOS Registration form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've overrided the FOS RegistrationFormType like this

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseRegistrationFormType;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('tel')
            ->add('sexe')
            ->add('date_naiss')
            ->add('ville')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('taille')
            ->add('poids')
            ->add('player_id')
            ->add('panier')
            ->add('pp')
            ->add('coupons');
    }
    
    public function getParent()
    {
        return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
    }
    
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }


}
```

I've configure the service.yml like this

```
app.form.registration:
    class: AdminBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

And the fosuserbundle to use my form type like this

```
registration:
    form:
      type: AdminBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

but when i use the form in view like this

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'needs-validation'}}) }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {# Génération du label. #}
                    {{ form_label(form.nom, "Votre Nom") }}
                        
                    {# Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis. #}
                    {{ form_errors(form.nom) }}
                    {# Génération de l'input. #}
                    {{ form_widget(form.nom, {'attr': {'class': 'nom'}}) }}
                    <div class="err" id="name-invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {# Génération du label. #}
                    {{ form_label(form.prenom, "Votre Prenom") }}
                        
                    {# Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis. #}
                    {{ form_errors(form.prenom) }}
                    {# Génération de l'input. #}
                    {{ form_widget(form.prenom, {'attr': {'class': 'nom'}}) }}
                    <div class="err" id="name-invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {# Génération du label. #}
                    {{ form_label(form.email, "adresse mail") }}

                    {# Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis. #}
                    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
                    {# Génération de l'input. #}
                    {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'email'}}) }}
                    <div class="err" id="email-invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        {# Génération du label. #}
                        {{ form_label(form.ville, "Ville") }}

                        {# Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis. #}
                        {{ form_errors(form.ville) }}
                        {# Génération de l'input. #}
                        {{ form_widget(form.ville, {'attr': {'class': 'ville'}}) }}

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        {# Génération du label. #}
                        {{ form_label(form.tel, "Numéro de téléphone") }}
                        
                        {# Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis. #}
                        {{ form_errors(form.tel) }}

                        {# Génération de l'input. #}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2" style="padding: 0px;margin-left: 10px;margin-right: -10px">
                                <input value="+ 237" readonly="readonly" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">    
                                {{ form_widget(form.tel, {'attr': {'class': 'tel'}}) }}
                                <div class="err" id="tel-invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        {# Génération du label. #}
                        {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first, "Mot de passe") }}

                        {# Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis. #}
                        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}

                        {# Génération de l'input. #}
                        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, {'attr': {'class': 'mdp'}}) }}
                        <div class="err" id="mdp-invalid-feedback"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        {# Génération du label. #}
                        {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second, "Confirmation") }}


                        {# Affichage des erreurs pour ce champ précis. #}
                        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
                        {# Génération de l'input. #}
                        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, {'attr': {'class': 'conf'}}) }}
                        <div class="err" id="conf-invalid-feedback"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {{ form_end(form) }}
```

but i have this error

*Neither the property "nom" nor one of the methods "nom()", "getprenom()"/"isnom()"/"hasnom()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView".*

and that's my register controller

```
public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $user->addRole('ROLE_CLIENT');
        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

            if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->render(
            '@App/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),)
        );
    }
```

Hope i'll get some help

Answer (score 0):

ok sorry my mistake i was overriding the wrong config.yml file and service.yml file now it work well.